# date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTime, string given

Tags: php, date, datetime, date-formatting

I'm trying to replace my queries to PDO query and I have problems with date formats. I need to print dates in format d/m/Y H:i:s but after PDO script runs it prints the date in this format Y-m-d H:i:s

```
    while($row = $sql -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
  {
  ...
echo "<td>" . date_format( $row['date'], 'd/m/Y H:i:s'). "";"</td>";
  ...

  }
Warning: date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTime, string given in
```

But if I change the code to `echo "<td>" . $row['date']. "";"</td>";`   then it returns to `Y-m-d H:i:s`
How can I get the previous format `d/m/Y H:i:s`?

Comment: the problem is already on the warning given to you, feed it right, it'll work correctly

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The first parameter to `date_format` needs to be an object of `DateTime` class.

```
echo "<td>" . date_format( new DateTime($row['date']), 'd/m/Y H:i:s' ). "</td>";
```

or, alternatively

```
echo "<td>" . date_format( date_create($row['date']), 'd/m/Y H:i:s' ). "</td>";
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your code to the following as provided in the PHP manual. As stated in the error you need to convert the value to DateTime object before outputting.

```
    while($row = $sql -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
  {
$date = new DateTime($row['date']);
  ...
echo "<td>" . $date->format( $row['date'], 'd/m/Y H:i:s'). "";"</td>";
  ...

  }
```